# Disable submit form button when the timer stops Javascript Html

Tags: javascript, html

Goodmorning all. Hi i have here my sample javascript and html codes. what i want is when the timer stops or finish the submit button will disable so that the users cannot submit their forms. I am currently developing small voting system.

Here's my code:

Javascript

```js
var callbackfunction = function ()
{
   console.log('Done!');
}
countdown('12/10/2017 06:26:00 AM', ['days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds'],
callbackfunction);
```

I have count.js that operates the timer.

And lastly my HTML Codes:

```html
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-query">
```

```html
<table style="margin: 0 auto;">
<tr>
<td class="header-tb" id="days">00</td>
<td class="header-tb" id="hours">00</td>
<td class="header-tb" id="minutes">00</td>
<td class="header-tb" id="seconds">00</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I just want to stop the user to attempt their submits when the time is over. Is this possible with my construction of codes?

Comment: What is `countdown()` doing? Do you have any sort of timeout already set?

Comment: used sir to set time when the timer will stop

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like:

```
if(timer >= 3600) {
    document.getElementById('your-button').disabled = true;
}
```